# Bad performance with rotation animation in swiftUI

Tags: swift, performance, animation, swiftui

I created a compass app with swiftUI, everything works correctly but some improvements could be made to the animation of the compass rotation. I recreated a project with only the compass to illustrate the point with code. On this version, no performance problem is to be reported, because there is only the compass in question to calculate. But on my real application, where there are more elements, the performance is not optimal.

Code of simple compass app:

(For a technical reason, I have to use `UIKit` with the `CGAffineTransform` to animate the compass rotation with a matrix rotation in order to avoid an unwanted effect)

Location provider:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Combine

public class LocationProvider: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate, ObservableObject {
  
  private let locationManager: CLLocationManager
  
  public let heading = PassthroughSubject<Double, Never>()
  
  @Published var currentHeading: Double {
    willSet {
      heading.send(newValue)
    }
  }
  
  public override init() {
    currentHeading = 0
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    super.init()
    
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
  }
  
  public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    self.currentHeading = newHeading.magneticHeading
  }
}
```

Compass view:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

public extension CGFloat {
  var degreesToRadians: CGFloat { return self * .pi / 180 }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
  @ObservedObject var location: LocationProvider = LocationProvider()
      
  private var windowWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
  
  @State private var heading: CGFloat = .zero
  
  // Arrow view
  struct ArrowView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var angle: CGFloat
    var width: CGFloat
    var height: CGFloat
    var container: UIView = UIView()
    var imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    var imageName: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
      
      // Container
      container.frame = CGRect.init(
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: height < width ? height : width,
        height: height < width ? height : width
      )
      container.isOpaque = true
      
      // Image
      imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
      imageView.frame = CGRect.init(
        x: height < width ? 0 : 20,
        y: height < width ? 0 : 20,
        width: height < width ? height : width - 40,
        height: height < width ? height : width - 40
      )
      imageView.isOpaque = true
      
      container.addSubview(imageView)
      
      return container
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
        uiView.subviews[0].transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -angle.degreesToRadians)
      }, completion: nil)
      
      // Mise à jour de l'image
      let imageView = uiView.subviews.compactMap{ $0 as? UIImageView }
      imageView[0].image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    }
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      ArrowView(angle: self.heading, width: self.windowWidth - 20, height: self.windowWidth - 20, imageName: "arrow")
        .frame(width: self.windowWidth, height: self.windowWidth, alignment: .center)
    }
    .onReceive(self.location.heading) { heading in
      self.heading = CGFloat(heading)
    }
  }
}
```

I have looked for several ways to solve the problem, but I am not sure what the best ways to follow.

- Separate the code into a subcomponent?
- Use SpriteKit to animate compass?
- I read that a method could be to do some tasks outside of the main thread?

Answer (score 2):

You're re-creating that view each and every time that SwiftUI invalidates the view due to a heading change. Without profiling it, I can't be 100% sure, but that's the first thing that sticks out to me.

Two options:

The first is translate the drawing code into SwiftUI native, using Path and Shape, or Image if you're just spinning a pre-defined image around. Then leverage the rotation using the [rotationEffect view modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/rotationeffect(_:anchor:)). SwiftUI will be far more aggressive at caching the images that don't need to change because you're only applying rotation to them.

The second is to apply the rotation in the SwiftUI view, which will keep the underlying UIView rendering cached for you - that means moving the rotation and animation into SwiftUI. You mentioned an unwanted effect causing you to use CGAffineTransform, but the result of doing the rotation at that level is that you're re-blitting that image into a newly constructed view every time there's an update, and that's just expensive.

I'd advise working with SwiftUI's [Image](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image) view, [Shape &/or Path](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/drawing-paths-and-shapes) if you want to do custom lines, and [rotationEffect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/rotationeffect(_:anchor:)) for the heavy lifting. I made a similar thing myself while playing with Combine, and the result was quite effective and performant.